# c# - Problems during AJAX call with Jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

Good evening,
I'm trying to do a AJAX call in a C# page and I'm dealing with some problems.

My jQuery code is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "conteudo.aspx/GetNewPost",
        data: { ids: "<%=Request.QueryString["idconteudo"]%>" },
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Request: " + XMLHttpRequest.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert("ok");
        }
    });
});
```

And my code-behind is:

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string GetNewPost(string ids)
    {
        // some code
        return ids;
    }
```

Does someone know what is going on?
PS: The error is `Internal Server Error`.

[image]

Comment: first, don't forget to escape your string: `ids: "<%=Request.QueryString[\"idconteudo\"]%>"`

Comment: your json is incorrect. ids should be "ids"

Comment: @nicovank It's right. This is not a text, it's a C# function.

Comment: @viveknuna I tried that. The problem has not been solved.

Comment: Pass some static value to it and see if error goes away. start debugging from validating URL and parameters. FYI : Content Type is type of data you are sending to server while dataType is type of data you are expecting back from server.

Comment: *i'm trying to do a AJAX call in a C# page and i'm dealing with some problems.*... **exactly** what problems?  Also can you post more than just `Internal Server Error`?

Comment: @viveknuna is correct in saying that `ids` should be `"ids"`. Also, just to make this cleaner, what about putting `"<%=Request.QueryString["idconteudo"]%>"` into a `var` and then just saying `"ids" : var`? Are you receiving the values that you expect when you debug?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid Only that: [imgur.com](http://imgur.com/a/1wR9N)

Comment: @Jecoms Url path is right.

Comment: @LucasS.Müller If you put `"<%=Request.QueryString["idconteudo"]%>"` into a separate variable.. and then alerted that variable.. are you receiving what you expect?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid Yes, i'm receiving the `1345` from: `http://url.com/conteudo.apsx?idconteudo=1345`, for example.

Comment: What happens to `<%=Request.QueryString["idconteudo"]%>` when you load the page without a queryString? That's probably the error.

Comment: If you open the console and go to the networks tab you should be able to view the request and response.  First make sure the request is correct.  Then look at the response.  Assuming you don't have custom error messages on then you should be able to view a stack trace inside the response.  Alternative you can debug into the AJAX error method and view the result.  My guess is you have a null reference exception but knowing for sure would help.

Comment: data: { 'ids': "<%=Request.QueryString["idconteudo"]%>" },
Remove  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

Comment: try `data: { 'ids' : "<%=Request.QueryString["idconteudo"]%>" }`

Comment: @nurdyguy The response: `{"Message":"Houve um erro ao processar a solicitação.","StackTrace":"","ExceptionType":""}`

Comment: @rach New error with that changes: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 4`.

Comment: @LucasS.Müller what happens if, before you do the `ajax` call, you write this `var test = <%=Request.QueryString["idconteudo"]%>;   alert(test)`? Does `test` get filled with the appropriate value?

Comment: what kind of data you are receiving back from server? is it json? because in the code you are returning ids which is string!

Comment: try datatype: text or html

Comment: Have you tried using `data: JSON.stringify(theModel),`  Depending on the specific version of .net this might or might not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use code as below

**Because you are using text data type from query string, you can make datatype as `text`**

```
$(document)
        .ready(function () {
            var q = "<%=Request.QueryString["idconteudo"]%>";
            alert(q);// just to check the value
            // assuming that you had passed query string value

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "conteudo.aspx/GetNewPost",
                data: { "ids": q },
                //contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'text',// data type should be text
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("Request: " +
                        XMLHttpRequest.toString() +
                        "\n\nStatus: " +
                        textStatus +
                        "\n\nError: " +
                        errorThrown);
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    alert("ok");
                }
            });
        });
```

**Edit 1** : If the Web Method is on ASPX page, you shall use below code, so that you get result in Json format

```
$(document)
        .ready(function () {
            var q = "<%=Request.QueryString["idconteudo"]%>";
            //alert(q);
            // just to check the value
            // assuming that you had passed query string value

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "conteudo.aspx/GetNewPost",
                data: '{ids: "' + q + '" }',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("Request: " +
                        XMLHttpRequest.toString() +
                        "\n\nStatus: " +
                        textStatus +
                        "\n\nError: " +
                        errorThrown);
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    alert("ok" + result.d);
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Worked '0'. Thank you.

Comment: @LucasS.Müller lol basically the same answer as mine.. how'd mine get downvoted?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid It was not me.

Comment: And one more problem. The fully page conteudo.aspx is the response. :/ WTF

Comment: @LucasS.Müller are you using razor?

Comment: What's that? @BviLLe_Kid

Comment: @LucasS.Müller what happens when you just do `url: "/GetNewPost"`

Comment: @LucasS.Müller: For your problem `fully page conteudo.aspx is the response` , i realized that your method is in aspx page. Please check edit 1, as other option, that will fix the problem. It is tested on asp.net 4.0

Answer (score 0):

try:

var idconteudo = "<%=Request.QueryString["idconteudo"]%>";

...
...
url: "conteudo.aspx/GetNewPost",
data: "{ids: \"" + idconteudo + "\"" }",
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
...
...

Comment: Syntax error on that line: `data: "{ids: \"" + idconteudo + "\"" }",`

Comment: that means Request.QueryString["idconteudo"] contains something like quotation marks. you would better escape all quotation marks in value of that.

Answer (score -1):

From what you have given us with your post, I see two things that are incorrect and one other thing that may have just not been posted in your question, but it is in fact in your real source.

1) Your `data` is written wrong.  It should be:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var test = "<%=Request.QueryString["idconteudo"]%>";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "conteudo.aspx/GetNewPost",
        data: { 'ids' : test }, // the ids needs to have quotes to be correct syntax
        dataType: 'text',
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Request: " + XMLHttpRequest.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert("ok");
        }
    });
});
```

2) You say it's a `POST` but your method isn't decorated with the `[HttpPost]` Annotation.

3) Your `dataType` is set to `'json'` but your method is returning a `string`.. so `'json'` should be changed to `'text'`.

Hope this helps!